# Data quality vs Data reliability

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm having some trouble with some word usages in certain sentences.

1. Data quality
2. Data reliability

The sentences:

_________ is the reliability and application efficiency of data.

_________ is a measure of the overall integrity of the data over specific durations of time.

I think that "Data quality" fits the first one better, because "Data reliability is the reliability...." kinda doesn't make sense.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where do the sentences come from?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty my uni textbook

Comment: The textbook for what subject?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty English for natural sciences

Comment: Your logic seems fine but neither sentence makes much sense to the general reader.

Comment: @GL02 I agree with your comment about repetition of "reliability", but the terms "quality" and "reliability" aren't well defined there, and the sentences they are attached to don't clear anything up. Maybe the textbook quality (or its reliability) is questionable.

Comment: Data reliability is the reliability of data, isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko unfortunately reliability is used in several different senses in lay and scientific jargon.